# Real time Job Scheduling web application using Quartz with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I am a beginner of [Quartz](https://quartz-scheduler.org/).My requirement is something like this.I have already created java web application.there are some tasks stores in the Data base.To communicate with DB i use hibernate query language.There are plenty of jobs stores inside the DB table to be run.

**job table**

***jobName***       ***runDate***           ***status***

1.createUsers   | 2015/5/13 1.30pm       | schedule

2.UpdateUsers   | 2015/5/13 10am         | schedule

i want to implement a job listener for jobs and execute jobs when exact date come.I have gone through some articles available in internet but not much clear to me.I would like to know that how can i run a job listener time to time that check whether job is ready to execute if ready that will fetch data using HQL and run jobs. Appreciate your ideas.

Comment: Visit http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/ ....it has explained how to use quartz with spring in java application. Nice and elegant explaination

Comment: yes it is but the problem is users can crate job task also.its dynamic.so how can i watch those jobs and execute when date come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a good article that let us know how to do curd operations using quartz in dynamically.The above posted answers are also fine but the problem is that all jobs creation and execution in a static way.but my requirement was that jobs should be created in dynamic way.This [article](http://blog.xebia.in/2012/06/15/create-update-and-delete-jobs-dynamically-in-quartz/) will help you to get some idea about how we can create execute delete jobs in run time.All credits go to article author :).I shared this because of lot of peoples looking for that kind of thing but the article is not much popular.here is the steps i have followed.

1. Create a database for store the job details.

   The reason was for that every time we restart the server our jobs wont be discard.
2. Fetch stored jobs from DB and assign each job to a quartz Job scheduler.
3. Configure Spring frame work to contiguously execute the `PersistentJobSchedulerJob` class.

   Hope this will help for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You need not check time to time whether a  job is ready and needs to be executed or not. That is where Quartz comes into picture.

Case 1: When Jobs are known when to be executed
In this case you can use cron trigger as mentioned in the [Mkyong tutorial](http://mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example)

Case 2: When Jobs execution times are dynamic i.e. not known earlier in time.
In this case, you need to autowire the scheduler(or get from spring application context) in your java class. you can schedule jobs dynamically by invoking scheduleJob() method on the scheduler with your custom jobs. [Mkyong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/example-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-quartz/).

For every scheduled job, there will be a trigger which will have trigger key, you can unschedule by using unscheduleJob(triggerKey) on Quartz scheduler instance.

As soon as you know a job needs to be run at a particular time, you can schedule the job with Quartz scheduler. Quartz scheduler will take care of executing the job at the scheduled time.

Note:- Trigger and Job bean classes in the Quartz dependencies vary based on the versions. Make changes appropriately

Comment: plz, can you accept the answer if it worked for you?